# Can Catholics participate in a regime or administration that lies to protect its people?

Tags: catholicism, morality, civil-government, lying

An [article in Slate](https://slate.com/technology/2021/07/noble-lies-covid-fauci-cdc-masks.html) describe "Noble Lies" as:

> When experts or agencies deliver information to the public that they consider possibly or definitively false to further a larger, often well-meaning agenda, they are telling what is called a noble lie.

This would seem to bad at odds with Catholic [moral principles against lying](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/09469a.htm)

But I can't see which category of lie "noble lies" fall into.  I'd assume a noble like is not a joke (even the president would tell you that), and it's not a white lie (it's a big lie, repeated ad nauseam), and it's definitely not funny. Neither is it an accidental falsehood, it's just a falsehood. It is incorrect and deliberate.

But, if it were wrong and one worked for an administration that told these kinds of lies, what level of formal cooperation would one have with these lies?  Should someone merely resign or be a whistleblower?

Comment: Are you hoping that there is actually a government out there that does not lie! Do not all regimes lie!

Comment: Another point is that some states allow police to lie during interrogations, yet to lie to police is a crime! That has always made no sense to me morally.

Comment: The concept of "Noble Lie" [originated from Plato's Republic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noble_lie).  Since it's ancient, I'm sure early church fathers steeped in Plato would have commented on it from natural law or other Christian morality framework, which would then form the basis of the answer.

Comment: @ken yeah, I'd have a hard time with that one if I were an officer.  That can be a form of torture, I hope nobody qualifies it as a Noble Lie.   I'd prefer the kind of lie where they say one thing and do another rather than the kind of lie that is just grandiose Neurolinguistic Programming.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple I don't think I've ever ran across the term in Catholic doctrine.  I guess it's an "officious lie" `Now it is evident that the greater the good intended, the more is the sin of lying diminished in gravity. Wherefore a careful consideration of the matter will show that these various kinds of lies are enumerated in their order of gravity`, just seems like we've got Dr. Fauci as a guy who is habituated to lying to the public, which is a credibility problem.  I think these matters are far different when practiced on personal scale than a national one.

Comment: @PeterTurner After reading the *Slate* article in full, I agree that in this high information-accessibility era and the presence of highly educated citizenship, Noble lies are a lot more damaging.  Rather, let the data (and its insufficiency) speak for themselves and then present recommendation, similar to how webmd.com deals with a lot of unknowns in medical & drug research.  Good moral guidance for noble lie needs to take moral situations seriously (i.e. not abstract reasoning) by including audience education, data ambiguity, long-term trust, institutional credibility, preventing panic, etc.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple either that, or just tell the truth and deal with it.  It could be that Plato was wrong about that,  Jesus said "let your yes mean yes", He didn't say "Let your 70% mean 85%", but He did say "anything else was from the evil one"

Comment: Tell me a regime that does not lie in order to protect the people and you may have an answer!!!!

Comment: @PeterTurner After reading more into Plato's Noble lie, I think the *Slate* article cheapens the meaning a lot.  What Dr. Fauci did doesn't deserve to be called "noble lie".  Noble lie is on the level of national / cultural "myth" on par with faith in America's exceptionalism or America as the New Jerusalem (like what the Puritans did) or in believing God is good, or how Israel believe they're the chosen people, etc. so that the whole society is willing to share a unifying narrative that binds the society together and enable them to make sacrifices for the greater good.

Comment: Good question. Id consider adding “Assume that..” to “It's not a joke (even the president would tell you that), it's not a white lie (it's a big lie, repeated ad nauseum), and it's definitely not funny. **And** it's not an accidental falsehood. **It's** just wrong (as in incorrect) and deliberate.” Because I kept thinking you were referring to something in particular.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple I don't think the myth that cloth masks protect you from coronaviruses; the myth that six feet of separation is better than short periods of exposure; the myth that vaccines necessarily offer better protection than acquired immunity; or the myth that there is no effective treatment for covid-19 qualifies as noble.

Comment: But I don't think lies about rigged elections, the danger of antifa and communism or critical race theory / gender ideology are entirely noble either.

Comment: @PeterTurner *I don't think the myth that ..... qualifies as noble*.  Completely agree with you.  What Plato meant was something a **lot** more "noble", very different than the *Slate* definition you quoted.  We are talking about two completely different things, so *Slate* definition should be named something different like ["paternalistic lie"](https://hbr.org/2018/09/when-is-it-ok-to-tell-a-well-meaning-lie) because I can defend Plato's "noble lie" but not "paternalistic lie".

Comment: @PeterTurner I found a very pertinent [book chapter](https://philarchive.org/archive/STOPLA-4) in the 2018 *Routledge Handbook of the Philosophy of Paternalism* covering different kinds of paternalistic lying (this confirms that "paternalistic" is the term that *Slate* should have used) contrasted with the more general "altruistic lie" or your view (Absolutism), Anti-Absolutism, and various issues related to it: Manipulation, Paternalism without deception, Lying and interfering, Right to Autonomy, Obligations, Consequences.  Good for exposing all angles to form the Catholic teaching on it.

Answer (score 1):

St. Vincent Ferrer, following Gratian's [*Decretals*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_list&search=authors:%22%3DGratian%22) (an early *corpus iuris canonici*, "body of canon law"), defended the notion of **simulated authority**.

Philip Daileader, [*Saint Vincent Ferrer, His World and Life*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=6198), p. 22:

> Vincent also cited the [*Decretum*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_list&search=authors:%22%3DGratian%22) in defense of the cardinals who, rather than allowing themselves to be killed, had elected Urban [during the [Great Western "Schism"](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/58831/3202)] and pretended to be happy to do so when in truth they were deathly afraid; as the [*Decretum*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_list&search=authors:%22%3DGratian%22) says, there was **biblical precedent for “useful simulation.”** [[*Tractatus de moderno ecclesie scismate*, 36](https://books.google.com/books?id=tHiLeyZVTUkC&pg=PA36), [69](https://books.google.com/books?id=tHiLeyZVTUkC&pg=PA69).]

[*Tractatus*, 69](https://books.google.com/books?id=tHiLeyZVTUkC&pg=PA69) cites the biblical evidence given in Gratian's [*Decretals*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_list&search=authors:%22%3DGratian%22):

> [*Gratian's Decretals*, Second Part](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=7863), Cause XXII, question II, ch. 21, col. 873: Likewise **St. Jerome**. [[*Commentary on Galatians*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=7524) [2:11](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=55&ch=2&l=11-#x)-13], pp. 106-7.]:
>
> > For another example of how **temporary deception can be expedient**, let us consider Jehu, the king of Israel. He would not have been able to kill the priests of Baal unless he had feigned a desire to worship this false god, and he said, “Assemble all the priests of Baal for me, for Ahab served Baal in a few respects, I shall serve him in many.” [[2 Kgs 10.18](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=12&ch=10&l=18-#x)-19.] Another example is when David altered his appearance, pretending to be somebody else in Abimelech’s presence, and Abimelech dismissed him. [Cf. [1 Sm 21.13](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=9&ch=21&l=13-#x).] That even very righteous men resort to temporary dissimulation for the sake of their own or others’ salvation is not surprising when we recall that our Lord himself, who was free of iniquity and whose flesh was not sinful, pretended to take on sinful flesh so that by condemning sin in his flesh he might make us the righteousness of God.
>
> ---
>
> <sub>[*Decretum Gratiani*, Secunda Pars](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=7863), Causa XXII, questio II, c. 21, col. 873 : Item Ieronimus. [in epist. ad Galatas, c. 2.] : Utilem simulationem et in tempore assumendam, Ieu regis Israel nos doceat exemplum, qui, cum non potuisset interficere sacerdotes Baal, nisi finxisset se idolum velle colere, dicens: "Congregate mihi omnes sacerdotes Baal. Achab servivit ei in paucis, ego serviam sibi in multis." Et David, quando mutavit faciem suam coram Abimelech, et dimisit eum, et abiit. Nec mirum quamvis iustos homines tamen aliqua simulare pro tempore ob suam et aliorum salutem, cum et ipse Dominus noster, non habens peccatum, nec carnem peccati, simulationem peccatricis carnis assumpsit, ut, condemnans, in carne peccatum, nos in se faceret iustitiam Dei.</sub>

[Gal. 2:11](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=55&ch=2&l=11-#x)-13:

> But when Cephas was come to Antioch, I withstood him to the face, because he was to be blamed. For before that some came from James, he did eat with the Gentiles: but when they were come, he withdrew and separated himself, fearing them who were of the circumcision. And to his **dissimulation** the rest of the Jews consented: so that Barnabas also was led by them into that **dissimulation**.

<sup>Cf. [St. Thomas Aquinas's commentary on this](https://isidore.co/aquinas/SSGalatians.htm#23).</sup>

<sup>Dissimulation is "a lie told by the signs of outward deeds" ([*Summa Theologica* II-II q. 111 a. 1](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS111.html#SSQ111A1THEP1) co.).</sup>

<sup>For how Abraham saying Sarah was his sister, Jacob saying he was Esau, and Judith deceiving Holofernes to kill him were not really lies, see [*Summa Theologica* II-II q. 110 a. 3](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS110.html#SSQ110A3THEP1) "Whether every lie is a sin?" arg./ad 3: Abraham "wished to hide the truth, not to tell a lie, for she is called his sister since she was the daughter of his father"; "Jacob's assertion […] was spoken in a mystical sense"; Judith's "words contain truth in some mystical sense."</sup>

Comment: I'm rather surprised St. Jerome didn't include Abram and Sarai pretending to be brother and sister, that was a useful deception - but probably a wrong-headed one once they got caught.  Seems like there may be contexts where it's sinful.

Comment: @PeterTurner St. Thomas discusses Abraham saying Sarah was his sister (and Jacob saying he was Esau and Judith lying to Holofernes) in [_Summa Theologica_ II-II q. 110 a. 3](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS110.html#SSQ110A3THEP1) "Whether every lie is a sin?" arg./ad 3. St. Jerome probably doesn't mention these examples because they're not cases of a political leader saving his subjects (Abraham and Jacob weren't kings; Judith wasn't a queen). The apostles had authority over many people.